# Why Math.pow(long, (1/3)) always returns 1?

Tags: java, math

If problem is in power, how to write it correctly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `Math.pow(long, 1D/3)`.

By default, numeric literals in Java are considered as ints. So, 1/3 is converted to 0 and not 0.33333 as should be the case. Qualifying it with 1D or 1F or 1.0 will solve the problem.

Answer (score 28):

This is because `1/3` is integer division, and it evaluates to `0`.  You are effectively raising to the 0th power, which always yields 1.  Try `1.0/3.0` instead.